# What to do with the many uint tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

I just noticed that we have a lot of tags like these:

[uint8t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uint8t) [uint16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uint16) [uint32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uint32) [int32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int32) [uint64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uint64) [int64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int64)

The first one is probably referring to C/C++ `uint8_t` from stdint.h, though oddly there's also a lot of Python questions using that tag. Presumably because there is no `uint8` tag.

The question is: are these tags meaningful to have?

Those without the 't' are used wildly across all kinds of languages and platforms. It seems that they are mostly used to describe what the question contains, not necessarily what it is about.

At any rate, the tags are inconsistent: there is no `uint8` nor `int8`. The `uint8t` seems to be the only one used out of all possible types in stdint.h. Some of the tags have their signed equivalent, some don't.

At the very minimum, I think we should rename `uint8_t` to `uint8`. Questions about the C/C++ stdint.h types should be tagged with [stdint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdint), or we could in theory have countless tags. (There's also the `uint_fast` and `uint_least` types, and their signed equivalents).

Comment: They are pretty decent contextual tags, adding info to tags that are too broad like [python] or [c].  I don't see other tags being used along with it, other than the language tag, so they must be selective enough.  Answer rates are very high.  Avoid fixing anything, it ain't broken.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure there's a problem (apart from the uint8t nit-pick), only that the tags are inconsistent. This isn't a burninate or retag request, just a discussion, as I'm not sure which action, if any, that is the most suitable.